# embed swf with swfobject and external interface calls

Tags: jquery, interface, external, swfobject

I am using swf object to embed swf:

```
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "flashPreview";
        params.quality = "high";
        params.scale = "noscale";
        params.salign = "tl";
        params.wmode = "transparent";
        params.bgcolor = "#111";
        params.devicefont = "false";
        params.allowfullscreen = "true";
        params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
        swfobject.embedSWF("preview.swf", "flashPreview", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

In my swf I am using external interface addCallback to communicate with jquery.

This works fine but the problem comes when I take original div in which swf was embeded and reparent it to another element in the dom, after that these methods in my swf are not recognized any more.

So after I do this:
playlistThumb.append(myFlashPreview);
these methods in swf become undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't create another swfobject.embedSWF to the other element ?